# Is there such thing as a guest session on a system without a GUI?

Tags: login, guest-session

I know that guest sessions can be disabled in Ubuntu from `lightdm.conf`. Is this something specific to systems with X installed or is it possible to have a guest session also on systems without a GUI (i.e. servers)?

Comment: How would a "guest" differ from an anon user connecting over "ftp"?

Comment: @Rinzwind in the latter case, the ftp server doesn't create a system account, and does some permission checking internally rather than relying on the filesystem code. Totally different situation to an interactive (graphical or terminal) login.

Comment: Not when it comes to permissions on a server.  All you do is limit a guest  to its /home/. And no it is not that different to an tty login as you make it out to be. I would set  this up in for instance /etc/profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guest sessions lightdm runs use temporary accounts handled entirely by lightdm, created on request. If you wanted to have guest sessions without using lightdm, you'd have to handle the set-up and tear-down of temporary user accounts yourself. I'm not aware of any packages which will take care of this for you at the point of logging in at the terminal.

I guess if you really wanted to do this you might be able to implement it as a custom PAM module, but depending on what you actually want to set up, there might be an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is possible if you mount the `/home` partition as `tmpfs`, and create a guest user account.

If you want to do no modifications at all, you have to mount the entire filesystem as `tmpfs`, since even if the user can't modify system files without root permission, system daemons and services can.

I don't think this is what you want, and I find very little use of a guest account on a server.

Comment: Strictly, it should suffice to create a folder inside `/home` (this being the guest user's homedir) and mount a tmpfs *there*. Of course, unless you have a special setup procedure that mounts a new tmpfs and populates it from /etc/skel, guest account data will persist across logins, just not reboots. Regardless, the question seems more to have been about whether there's a need to *dis*able guest console login. And to *that*, the answer is "no, unless an ambitious admin previously implemented it from scratch and then enabled it".

Comment: @Darael: If you mount the entire filesystem as `tmpfs`, you just does not need even to remove the guest user after a reboot or shutdown. It's more simple and safe IMHO.

Comment: true, but that makes guests coexisting with permanent users an awful lot trickier.